# Must 'are' follow 'nor'?

Tags: conjunctions, ellipsis

> Great campaigns aren’t easily forgotten. Nor are those who created them.

I want to change the above to:

> Great campaigns aren’t easily forgotten, Nor those who created them.

Would that be grammatically correct?

Comment: Grammatically correct, but incorrectly capitalized. English does not capitalize random words after commas.

Comment: I prefer your first sentence, though I would put a comma after "forgotten" and ditch the capital N. Another option is: Neither great campaigns nor those who created them are easily forgotten. Just a suggestion.

Comment: This looks like a case of ellipsis to me. The "full" sentence would be "..., nor are those who created them easily forgotten". Of course the last part "easily forgotten" is almost always elided because it is clear from the first part of the sentence. I would say that similarly, the verb of the second part _can_ be omitted, as it can be filled in from the preceding part, however whether to do this is more a matter of preference (as opposed to leaving out the part at the end which is something almost everyone would do unless they're trying to make a specific stylistic point).

Answer (score 2):

The OP's first statement is OK grammatically.

The second sentence doesn't seem correct; there should be "are" after nor as follows:

Great campaigns aren't easily forgotten, nor are those who created them.

Answer (score 0):

> [Nor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nor) - Used to introduce a further negative statement:
> *the struggle
> did not end, nor was it any less diminished*

So if we look at the definition, yes this would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

*Created* in both sentences should be *create*.  Unless context suggests otherwise, you are not talking about specific completed "great campaigns" in the past, but great campaigns in a general sense.  So this is a case for the simple present tense.

If you are referencing specific great campaigns, then you want to say

> These great campaigns aren't easily forgotten, nor are those who created them.

---

The two things you are "conjuncting" with *nor* is "*Great campaigns*" and "*those who create them*."

So really the "best" sentence that requires the listener to keep the least "state" in his/her mind is this:

> Great campaigns, nor those who create them, aren't easily forgotten.

because generally it's clearest if you don't separate the two phrases of an *or* or *nor* conjunction - i.e. if both occupy the same spot as is expected for the subject or object of a sentence/phrase/clause.

But this also has the least dramatic effect.

In which case the second sentence is 100% ok (after fixing the capitalization and changing *created* to *create*).

Comment: Your less stateful version strikes me as the more difficult to parse.  *Hamburgers, nor those who eat them, are not readily found in vegan restaurants.*